# why in karma when i pass in a fake array to a function am i returned undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I have my function which I'm testing :

```
var depotItems = [1,2,3];

$scope.depotSortFunction = function (depotItems) {
    depotItemsAndCheckedValues = depotItems.map(function (value) {
        return { "val": value, "checked": false };
    });
        return depotItemsAndCheckedValues;
    }
```

and my karma test:

```
it("should arrange an array into object with extra value for entities + depots", inject(function (shareDataService) {
        var dummyEntityArray = ["ent1","ent2","ent3"];

        expect(mainScope.entitySortFunction).toBeDefined();
        spyOn(mainScope, 'entitySortFunction');
        mainScope.entitySortFunction(dummyEntityArray);
        console.log(mainScope.entitySortFunction(dummyEntityArray));
        expect(mainScope.entitySortFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dummyEntityArray);

    }))
```

So far the test is a green light, but I want to test the output of the `entitySoryFunction`.  However on this line `console.log(mainScope.entitySortFunction(dummyEntityArray));` when I check the logs I get Undefined.

Why is this?  I'm returning my new object value within my function.

EDIT -

Karma output for console.log - `LOG: undefined`

Comment: Try calling `spyOn(mainScope, 'entitySortFunction').and.callThrough();`,  if you don't call that the spy will not execute your implementation.

Comment: Bingo, brilliant.  I've a little reading up to do on spies obviously.  Thanks for the pointer.  If you feel this worthy of an answer fire away I'll accept it..

Comment: Also, why in the logs is the output in this format - `LOG: [Object{val: 'ent1', checked: false}, Object{val: 'ent2', checked: false},
Object{val: 'ent3', checked: false}]`  I.E. with "Object" before each object. How can I test this against the expeced output?

Comment: Don't know you can ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `spyOn(mainScope, 'entitySortFunction').and.callThrough();`, if you don't call that the spy will not execute your implementation.

[documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E)